# Overlapping (intersection) of two points is wrong. It should depends on which value is higher

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams

[image]

My problem is: Some points are overlapping. But sometimes the overlapping of this points is wrong. The intersection of this 2 points should be filled with the color of the point with the higher value. The value is the third column of my data table with the name "myvalue". 
Thank you for your support.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=0.2,colorbar]
\addplot[
scatter,mark=diamond*,only marks,
point meta=\thisrow{myvalue}
]
table {
x y  myvalue
0.5 0.63    0.25
3.2 5.91    0.75
0.7 0.119   0.125
0.35    0.2 2
3.65    0.7 0.175
0.2 0.35    0.225
0.7 0.63    0.275
0.35    0.91    3
0.65    0.119   0.325
0.2 0.2 0.375
2.7 0.7 0.425
0.35    3.35    4
7.65    0.63    0.475
0.2 0.91    0.525
0.65    0.119   0.575
6.2 0.147   5
0.7 0.175   0.625
0.35    3.203   0.675
0.65    2.231   0.725
0.2 0.259   6
5.65    0.287   0.775
0.2 0.315   0.825
0.7 0.343   0.875
0.35    0.371   7
0.65    0.399   0.925
0.2 0.427   2
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Higher means "larger graphical y value in the diagram"?

Comment: higher means the value of the point. See the colorbar. the size of all dots are always the same. It does not depends on the x and y value. it depends on the value of the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a 3D plot with `z buffer=sort`, viewed from the top for this. In that case, the `myvalue` column works both as the `meta` value for the colour, and the `z` value for the order.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=0.2,colorbar,
    view={0}{90}  % view the plot from the top
]
\addplot3[
    scatter,mark=diamond*,only marks,
    point meta=\thisrow{myvalue},
    z buffer=sort  % draw the points in the right order
]
table {
x y  myvalue
0.5 0.63    0.25
3.2 5.91    0.75
0.7 0.119   0.125
0.35    0.2 2
3.65    0.7 0.175
0.2 0.35    0.225
0.7 0.63    0.275
0.35    0.91    3
0.65    0.119   0.325
0.2 0.2 0.375
2.7 0.7 0.425
0.35    3.35    4
7.65    0.63    0.475
0.2 0.91    0.525
0.65    0.119   0.575
6.2 0.147   5
0.7 0.175   0.625
0.35    3.203   0.675
0.65    2.231   0.725
0.2 0.259   6
5.65    0.287   0.775
0.2 0.315   0.825
0.7 0.343   0.875
0.35    0.371   7
0.65    0.399   0.925
0.2 0.427   2
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```